# How to quickly traverse the diagonal of a matrix and assign elements?

Tags: python

I have a number of 2000*2000 matrices.

I need to go through each matrix's upper/lower diagonal, take each element, and calculate the mean of those elements in each upper/lower diagonal. Then I need to assign zero to the elements that are less than the mean.

I have tried a `for` loop, but it takes a long time because the dimensions of the matrix are too large.

How can I reduce the running time effectively?

```
def get_nth_diag_indices(mat, offset):
    rows, cols_orig = np.diag_indices_from(mat)
    cols = cols_orig.copy()
    if offset > 0:
        cols += offset
        rows = rows[:-offset]
        cols = cols[:-offset]
    return rows, cols

def normalize_along_diagonal_from_numpy(d, max_bin_distance, trim=0.01):
    for offset in range(1, max_bin_distance + 1):
        r, c = get_nth_diag_indices(d, offset)
        vals_orig = d[r, c].tolist()
        vals = vals_orig.copy()
        vals = list(filter(lambda num: num != 0, vals))
        vals.sort()
        vals.reverse()
        trim_index = round(trim * len(vals)) - 1
        if trim_index < 0:
            trim_index = 0
        remaining = vals[(trim_index):]
        if len(remaining) == 0:
            d[r, c] = [0] * len(vals_orig)
        else:
            mu = np.mean(remaining)
            sd = np.std(remaining)
            if sd < 1e-6:
                d[r, c] = [0] * len(vals_orig)
            else:
                d[r, c] = (d[r, c] - mu) / sd
                np.where(d[r, c] >= mu + sd, d[r, c], 0)
    ### replicate
    mat = d + d.T - np.diag(np.diag(d))
    return mat
```

Comment: If using a `numpy.array`, there is a `diagonal` (or similarly named) method which can be used to view the values on each diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np


def f(a):
    r = np.asarray(np.diag(np.diag(a)), dtype=np.float64) # keep main diagonal as it is
    for range_options in ((1, len(a[0])), (-len(a), 0)): # upper/lower diagonal
        for k in range(*range_options):
            diag = np.diag(a, k)
            new_diag = np.where(diag >= diag.mean(), diag, 0)
            r += np.diag(new_diag, k)
    return r


a = np.arange(16).reshape((4,4))
#array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
#       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
#       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

f(a)
#array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.],
#       [ 0.,  5.,  6.,  7.],
#       [ 0.,  9., 10., 11.],
#       [12., 13., 14., 15.]])
```

I changed the dtype to float and kept the main diagonal. In case you want to replace the main diagonal with zeros, you can replace the first line in function f with `r = np.zeros(a.shape)`. I don't know what execution time you are aiming for, but for a few matrices it runs fast enough. It is also more readable and utilizes numpy more. When aiming for performance, it is generally good to replace as many loops as possible with numpy methods. Especially lambda expressions are very slow.

Without using C, [Cython](https://cython.org/) or the [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) module, I doubt that you can reduce it to a few seconds.
If you [analyze](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-find-out-the-bottleneck-of-my-python-code-46383d8ef9f) my code for bottlenecks, you will find out that the creation of zero matrices (`np.diag`) takes a long time:
[image]
The time duration refers to a 2000x2000 matrix.